# Date format from Dutch to English

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a date in string format (i.e in Dutch language), like "7 juli 2013". I want to convert it in English format. "Convert.toDateTime(strValue) throw exception as that converts only English format. I also try this

```
   string strValue =   "7 juli 2013";

   CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
   strValue = strValue.ToString(ci);
```

but this is not working. What is the way to convert it?

Comment: convert it to a date time, then to the english. your converting a string which will not have any idea of what "juli" is between languages

Comment: The `"en-US"` culture loosely maps to English, unlike (`"en-GB"`) but, is fine for month names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string strValue = "7 juli 2013";

// Convert to DateTime
CultureInfo dutch = new CultureInfo("nl-NL", false);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strValue, dutch);

// Convert the DateTime to a string
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
strValue = dt.ToString("d MMM yyyy", ci);
```

You first convert the string to a `DateTime`, then .`ToString` the `DateTime`!

And, in general, it's false that `Convert.ToDateTime` uses only English. The overload you used uses the current culture of your pc (so on my pc it uses italian), and there is the `Convert.ToDateTime(string, IFormatProvider)` overload that accepts a `CultureInfo`.

Multilanguage... But note that this is wrong! You can't be sure that a word doesn't have different meaning in different places!!!

```
// The languages you want to recognize
var languages = new[] { "nl-NL", "it-IT" }; 

DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
bool success = false;

foreach (var lang in languages)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, new CultureInfo(lang, false), DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt))
    {
        success = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (success)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
    strValue = dt.ToString("d MMM yyyy", ci);
}
```

Comment: thanks xanatos, thats working nice. If there more than one languages not only Dutch then what i should do then, or in other words how i can check that the language of a string.

Comment: @RizwanAnsari Added another example.

Comment: Thanks Xanatos its pleasure to see that is working. Thanks again:-)